# Using Orbot android app as a proxy server for a windows client

Tags: windows, proxy, orbot, android

This might sounds strange but right now I am using the ProtonVPN android app as follow:

1. I connect my android device to home wifi
2. start ProtonVpn app
3. start Every Proxy app (usually using its HTTP option)
4. then connect my android device to windows laptop using cable and USB
   tethering option
5. then i add IP provided by Every Proxy app to proxy setting in Firefox and then
   start browsing

I tried the same with Orbot android app, but it did not work. What I want to know is that is there a way to use Orbot in the same manner as protonVPN? Using Orbot android vpn for my windows Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me.

First off apparently Orbot itself offers proxy so there is no need  for an extra app like Every Proxy.

Solution:

1. I used command `tracert` to find my android device IP when using in
   USB tethering mode, let say 192.168.164.5
2. then you need to go to Orbot setting and check the box that says
   "open proxy on all interfaces"
3. Then in the Orbot start page right under the start icon there are two
   numbers like Socks:9050|HTTP:8181 i guess these are the ports that
   Orbot listen on.
4. last step is to add the IP and and socks port, in this case
   192.168.164.5 and 9050, to Firefox proxy setting.

** I also tried this solution with HTTP port number but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

EverProxy is a *proxy* application and OrBot is a *VPN provider* like ProtonVPN - that's why you don't have it working. Yes, Android is a flavour of Linux - but, sadly, it's unable to fine-tune multiple VPN connections simultaneously. So - as you're starting ProtonVPN and Orbot afterward - Orbot's VPN **replaces** ProtonVPN's one...

Technically you can tweak it deeply by hand **if** you have LineageOS or AOSP with additional packages, but it's kinda a pain in the ass. To solve your problem without an effort that big - use an intermediate box. Buy Asus TinkerBoard or RaspberryPi 4 8G (**not a smaller memory version!**) - and make it a Tor routing box. So you will use your phone as you did before, then you will patch your box's Tor *through* its proxy and will expose Tor's DNS, SOCKS5s, and HTTPS proxy ports to your home WiFi/LAN (if you have a stationary router - plug it through a patch cord, it will work a way better!). That's it

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by simultaneously? i did not mean to have this two VPN work at the same time.

Comment: So you're running Tor only? Anyway - it wraps up **whole** system **and** it listens on localhost by default. Try to put it to your LAN ip or to 0.0.0.0